# Margin 0 auto not work in div with display:table cell

Tags: html, css

Im working on a page.. where Margin 0 auto not work in div with display:table cell
here's my code
CSS Styles

```
<style>
    html,body{
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    }
    .wrapper{
        background-color:#999;
        height:500px;
    }
    .tableContent{
        display:table;
        height:500px;
    }

    .tableContentRow{
        display:table-row;
    }

    .tableContentCell{
        display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:middle;
        height:500px;
    }

    .loginBox{
        height:100px;
        background-color:#FFF;
        width:250px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
</style>
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tableContent">
        <div class="tableContentRow">
            <div class="tableContentCell">
                <div class="loginBox">
                     <!-- More contents Go HEre -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The loginBox div does not position to the center of the tableContentCell div
Please help...

Comment: Not the solution but I left it in the left side and used full width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table itself is not centered.
Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trajce/hwkPs/).

```
.tableContent{
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set a specific width on the `.tableContentCell` div and you'll be ok.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonnysooter/xahmZ/1/)