# Margin Auto Doesn't Work With Table Cell

Tags: css

First of all i read [Margin 0 auto not work in div with display:table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881414/margin-0-auto-not-work-in-div-with-displaytable-cell) this question but i couldn't make it work. I want to center my div horizontally but it's not work with table-cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/mLmHR/850/

html

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="video">
  </div>
  <div id="info">
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  width: 70vw;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;

}

#video {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  background-color:yellow;
  height: 100%;
}

#info {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color:green;
  height: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a "wrapper"/container div around everything and give it a `display: table` and `margin: 0 auto`.

Something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="video">
        </div>
        <div id="info">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLmHR/853/).